# Print a string while record all components after the symbol %

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a pythonic function to print a string and meanwhile record the component.

Let's take an example. Suppose I have a string `s = "[D loss: %f, acc.: %.2f%%]" % (t[0], t[1]))`, I would like to design a function `rprint` so that it can both print `s` and record all the component in `s` after the `%`, which is `(t[0], t[1])` in this case.

```
global_list=[]
def rprint(s):
    print(s)
    global_list.append(t[0],t[1],...t[n])  # We don't know how many components in s.
```

Example

```
>>> global_list, t = [], (1,1)
>>> rprint("[D loss: %f, acc.: %f]" % (t[0], t[1])))
[D loss: 1, acc.: 1]
>>> global_list
[(1,1)]
```

I am wondering how to implement this function.

Comment: Why can't you just..`append(t)`? or `extend(t)` ?

Comment: @Alexander Reynolds Thanks. This `print` function is inside the training loop of different version of deep learning model. Instead of taking a glance into each model file and fix it by using `append(t)`, I would like to change the `print` into `rprint` once and for all.

Comment: So the only thing you have "access" to is whatever is being input into `print()`, correct? Which in this case would be the string *with* the interpolated values. There's no way to hook between that to get the variables on the right of the `%`, as for Python, it will evaluate the string *before* passing it into the function. However, you could store the string itself in the global list and then simply parse it.

Comment: @Alexander Reynolds Agree. The difficulty I am facing here is that I don't know whether the structure of a string with the interpolated values can be reversed or not. But I would leave the question here to see if there is any other inspiration for my situation.